# eBay API - FindItemsAdvanced call in PHP does not return any response

Tags: php, xml, ebay-api

Im trying to perform a simple call using ebays search API, when I make a call I get no response, and the problem is with the actual call itself.

```
$endpoint = 'http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?';  
$responseEncoding = 'XML';   
$version = '631';   // API version number
$appID   = 'asdf3e6e3'; 
$itemType  = "AllItemTypes";
$itemSort  = "EndTime";

//find items advanced
$apicalla  = "$endpoint"
    ."callname=FindItemsAdvanced"
    ."&version=$version"
    ."&siteid=0"
    ."&appid=$appID"
    ."&MaxEntries=10"
    ."&ItemSort=EndTime"
    ."&ItemType=AllItemTypes"
    ."&IncludeSelector=SearchDetails"
    ."&responseencoding=$responseEncoding";

    $resp = simplexml_load_file($apicalla);
```

this call is the equivalent to

```
http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=FindItemsAdvanced&version=631&siteid=0&appid=asdf3e6e3&MaxEntries=10&ItemSort=EndTime&ItemType=AllItemTypes&IncludeSelector=SearchDetails&responseencoding=XML
```

My question is what am I missing to make this simple search call?

Comment: Do you get anything back if you try `echo file_get_contents($apicalla)`? If not, then you've got a communication problem - url fopen may be disabled, outgoing http requests from the server may be blocked, ebay may have blacklisted your IP, etc...

Comment: sorry it does print something Marc, but I have made a getMostBooks call before and that seems to work well.

Comment: it returns `2012-05-02T19:05:05.024Z Failure Please specify a query! Please specify a query! 10.1 Error RequestError E771_CORE_BUNDLED_14784928_R1 771`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use eBay's [Shopping API](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/Shopping/docs/CallRef/index.html), specifically the `FindItemsAdvanced` call which I believe was deprecated quite some time ago and may no longer be functional (I no longer see it in the call reference). What you want to do is use use [`findItemsAdvanced`](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsAdvanced.html) from eBay's [Finding API](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/CallRef/index.html).

First, you'll need to change your API endpoint & query string parameters a bit (see the aforementioned `findItemsAdvanced` call reference for the specifics, but I believe it'll look more like this (I haven't touched my `findItemsAdvanced` calls in at least 6 months, so I haven't tested this):

```
$endpoint = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?';  
$responseEncoding = 'XML';   
$version = '1.8.0';   // API version number (they're actually up to 1.11.0 at this point
$appID   = 'asdf3e6e3'; 
$itemSort  = "EndTimeSoonest";

//find items advanced
$apicalla  = "$endpoint"
    ."OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced"
    ."&SERVICE-VERSION=$version"
    ."&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US"
    ."&SECURITY-APPNAME=$appID"
    //."&MaxEntries=10"    // look for an equivalent for this (maybe paginationInput.entriesPerPage?)
    ."&sortOrder=EndTimeSoonest"
    //."&ItemType=AllItemTypes"   // not needed AFAICT, otherwise look at itemFilterType
."&descriptionSearch=true";
    ."& RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=$responseEncoding";

$resp = simplexml_load_file($apicalla);
```

In addition to this, to use `findItemsAdvanced`, you must specify what you're searching for either by category (`categoryId`) or by keywords (`keywords`), hence the "Please specify a query!" error message.

So, you also need to add something like the following (assuming keywords):

```
$keywords = "something";
$apicalla .= "&keywords=" . urlencode($keywords);
```

Giving you the following:

```
$endpoint = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?';  
$responseEncoding = 'XML';   
$version = '1.8.0';   // API version number (they're actually up to 1.11.0 at this point
$appID   = 'asdf3e6e3'; 
$itemSort  = "EndTimeSoonest";
$keywords = "something";    // make sure this is a valid keyword or keywords

//find items advanced
$apicalla  = "$endpoint"
    ."OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced"
    ."&SERVICE-VERSION=$version"
    ."&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US"
    ."&SECURITY-APPNAME=$appID"
    //."&MaxEntries=10"    // look for an equivalent for this (maybe paginationInput.entriesPerPage?)
    ."&sortOrder=$itemSort"
    //."&ItemType=AllItemTypes"   // not needed AFAICT, otherwise look at itemFilterType
    ."&descriptionSearch=true";
    ."& RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=$responseEncoding"
    ."&keywords=" . urlencode($keywords);

$resp = simplexml_load_file($apicalla);
```

One final note: If you want to load further details of specific items that you find in your results, you'll still want to use the Shopping API (specifically the [GetSingleItem](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/Shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html) & [GetMultipleItems](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/Shopping/docs/CallRef/GetMultipleItems.html) calls). So, you may ultimately use a mix of the Shopping & Finding APIs.

Comment: this has not fixed the problem, i think there is something missing in the call string

Comment: i get something like `2012-05-02T22:04:39.405Z Success E771_CORE_BUNDLED_14784928_R1 771 150803837554 2012-05-02T22:04:39.000Z` followed by ebay URLs

Comment: Looking closer at your query, I see you're actually trying to use the old `FindItemsAdvanced` from the Shopping API which I believe has gone away for good. You'll want to use `findItemsAdvanced` from the Finding API. I've updated my answer extensively with this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&SERVICE-VERSION=1.11.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=YOUR_APP_ID&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=2&keywords=ipod&siteid=203&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-IN';
$xml = file_get_contents( $url );
$xml = simplexml_load_string( $url );
?>
```

Log-in to your ebay developer account and click on this link: [Test your calls with API Test Tool](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/build-test/test-tool/Default.aspx)

Hope this helps.